# Generate Texture in Silverlight imitate leather

Tags: silverlight, textures

I would like to display textures in different colors pretty much having this texture. 
How do I do this in Silverlight?
Thanks!

[alt text http://a.imageshack.us/img535/5255/leathertexture.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img535/5255/leathertexture.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your texture into alpha textue. Exact steps will depend on your image manipulation software. After that simply place your texture on top of colored rectangle.
You could make pixel shader for even better result, but that would be an overkill in your case.